Using 否応なし(に) as "Whether (we) like it or not"
I could not find many thorough explanations of the phrase いやおうなしに.
It seems to be used like ざるを得ない, in examples from explanations like:

社会的な圧力により、いやおうなしに環境保護活動に参加することになった。
->個人が社会からの期待や圧力を感じ、自分の本意ではないにもかかわらず、環境保護活動に参加することを示しています。

So I get that this is close to "whether (we) like it or not".
This phrase seems to be used at times like you were told by your boss to do something (like overtime) you don't want to do but have no choice, if most other people around you are doing something (like 飲み会) you don't want to do but due to peer pressure/obligation you do it any way, or if a friend/family member asks you to do something you don't want to but you feel you must.
In English we can usually just tie "whether I/we/you like it or not" to any phrase like "we cannot forget this history" or "I have work tomorrow" or "I need to be prepared for tomorrow".
Admittedly these English usages seem broad, so are there any specific cases where a sentence stating that you must do something, have an obligation, or must face something can not take this adverb? I guess I wonder if this word is only reserved for specific contexts since I feel that "whether I/we/you like it or not" is more common than 否応なしに (which perhaps is due to formality?).

応 is "accept" or "okay" rather than "like", so 否応なしに (or 否応なく) is closer to "without (a chance to say) no or okay". Typically, it's used in contexts where someone is made to do something almost forcibly, as seen in your example. In such cases, it may be often better to translate it explicitly as "against one's will".
Saying "whether you like it or not" in English leaves room for the possibility that you might like it, and it tends to be used for future events. On the other hand, 否応なしに usually doesn't allow for such a possibility, and is usually used for past or confirmed events (e.g., 否応なしに参加させられた).
The nuance of "forcibly" is strong enough that it's usually odd to say something like this:

[?] ルールは否応なしに守るものだ。
[?] Rules are something you are (always) forced to obey (against your will).

This almost sounds like this person hates every single rule in the world. Also, 否応なしに is not used when telling a fact that has nothing to do with your personal life (e.g., "Whether you like it or not, it's true that dinosaurs went extinct because of a meteor strike").
However, something like this is okay:

明日は否応なしにやってくる。
Tomorrow comes even if you hate it.

